# Corruption of the heap and how do i swap 2 values in a char* foobar [50]

Tags: c++, pointers, debugging, memory, heap-memory

This is my code, i dont understand why i am getting a Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'tempSign' was corrupted. I believe the error arises from trying to swap 2 values in the char* tempSign[MAX]. Can someone explain why i am getting this error and help me solve this problems thanks.

```
void constructSet(ZodiacSign *& z,int size)
{

    /*ZodiacSign is a char *
     This is how z was created from the previous function and 
     passed by reference

     ZodiacSign * z;
     z=new char* [num];

    for (int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        z[i]=new char [MAXSTR]; 
    } */

    ZodiacSign tempSign [MAX]={"aquarius","pisces","aries","taurus","gemini","cancer","leo",
                               "vergo","libra","scorpio","sagittarius","capricorn"};


    for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        int x=12;
        int num=(rand()%x);

        char * ptr=tempSign[num];
        strcpy(z[i],ptr);
        swap(num,x,tempSign);

        x--;
    }
}

void swap(int num,int x,ZodiacSign tempSign [MAX])
{
    ZodiacSign temp;

    temp=tempSign[num];

    tempSign[num]=tempSign[x-1];

    tempSign[x]=temp;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, and remove all the extraneous whitespace and commented-out code...

Comment: A lot of this would be much easier using `std::string`.

Comment: cant use the string class

Comment: Then make your own string class.

Comment: you have several `tempSign` variables. what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Also, I think it's `virgo` while you at it :)

Comment: @StuartLC - I think it's "you're" while you at it!  :)

Answer (score 6):

The first iteration of the loop in `constructSet` sets `x` to 12.  `swap` will then try to write to `tempSign[12]`.  C arrays are zero-based so valid indexes for `tempSign` are [0..11].  Writing to element 12 is undefined behaviour but is likely to scribble on the stack just beyond the end of memory allocated for `tempSign`.

You could fix this by changing the following line in `swap`

```
tempSign[x-1]=temp;
//        ^^
```